# How do you change the <img> src using XPath using PHP

Tags: php, xpath

i have

```
<?php
    echo "<div id='first'>
           <div id='getimg'> 
              <img src = 'mybyk.jpg'/> 
           </div>
          </div>";
?>
```

i am try to change the `img src` using xpath.
like :-

```
<?php
$doc = new DomDocument();
$doc->load("image.php");
$x = new DomXPath($doc);     
$re = $x->query("/div/img[@src]");
$m = $re->item(0)->SetAttribute("src","MyCar.jpg");
$doc->save("image.php");
?>
```

here i am try to find image src in img using xpath and if it is. then setAttribute src with my new image name
i am done successfully this
but when its save after all this then its contains top line in my new `image.php`
xml version like:-

`<?xml version="1.0"?>`
i don't want this.
how can i remove this.
and why its come.
thanks.

Comment: Are you asking how to change the <img> source? Or how to save a DomDocument without the `<?xml` line?

Comment: @jcsanyi yes i want to save DomDocument without the `<?xml` line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this?

```
file_put_contents('image.php', $doc->saveXML($doc->documentElement));
```

saveXML generates a string instead of saving directly to a file, but it allows you to specify a child node to start saving at. By specifying documentElement (which is the outer div), we're no longer saving the entire document, and the `<?xml` line is not generated.

Answer (score 0):

Not
`/div/img[@src]`

---

But

`/div/div/img[@src]`
or
`//div/img[@src]`
or
`//div[@id='getimg']/img[@src]`

Comment: yes this is my mistake but i want to save domdocument without the `<?xml` line